# PHP Upload & Crop Image

Tags: php, image, file-upload, upload, crop

I'm trying to create a php cropper based on other online tutorials but I keep coming up with errors and I can't understand what the actual errors mean. Here is my php code with the errors written in too:

```
<?php
include("settings.php");

$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["avatar"]["name"]));
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["id"]);
$time = time();
$avatarid= time().'-'.mt_rand(1000, 9999);
$avatar = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["avatar"]);
$w= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["w"]);
$h= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["h"]);
$x= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["x"]);
$y= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["y"]);
$rw = 300;
$rh = 300;

$path = "../uploads/avatars/";
$unlink = "$path$avatar";
$newimage = "$path$avatar";

$insert_avatar_sql = "UPDATE members SET avatar = '".$avatarid.".".$extension."' WHERE id = '$id'";
$insert_avatar_res = mysqli_query($con, $insert_avatar_sql);
if(mysqli_affected_rows($con)>0){
    unlink($unlink);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"],"$path" . $avatarid . "." . $extension);

    $wratio = ($rw/$w); 
    $hratio = ($rh/$h); 
    $newW = ceil($w * $wratio);
    $newH = ceil($h * $hratio);
    $newimg = imagecreatetruecolor($newW,$newH);
    $ext=$extension;
    if($ext=="jpg" || $ext=="jpeg" )
    {
        $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($newimage); // Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg(../uploads/avatars/1380641918-4496.jpg) [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\AppServ\www\music.co.uk\php\avatar.php on line 34
    }
    else if($ext=="png")
    {
        $source = imagecreatefrompng($newimage);
    }
    else 
    {
        $source = imagecreatefromgif($newimage);
    }
    imagecopyresampled($newimg,$source,0,0,$x1,$y1,$newW,$newH,$w,$h); // Warning: imagecopyresampled(): supplied argument is not a valid Image resource in C:\AppServ\www\music.co.uk\php\avatar.php on line 44
uploads/1380642027-5994
    imagejpeg($newimg,$path.$avatarid,90);
    echo "uploads/".$avatarid;
    exit;

    header("Location: ../edit.php?page=profile");
}
else{
header("Location: ../404.php");
exit();
}
?>
```

Please help me with this, I've been messing with Avatar uploads for 3 days solid now and I want to get this done, even if I have to use a different php script

Comment: The first error means it cant find the file which would cause the second error, what is the folder structure of your site?

Comment: The path is www.website.co.uk/uploads/avatars/ (IMAGE) - However for this the path has to go back out of the php folder and then into uploads, ../uploads/avatars/

Comment: So the file that is calling this is in www.website.co.uk/php/avatar.php

Comment: It still looks like a path issue (assuming the .jpg is valid).  Is this file use like example.com/php/avatar.php or is it call by another script in a require or include statement? show me the code that you use to post to this and a var_dump(); of a $_POST to this script.

Comment: Thanks @Pwner, I've sorted the script now and used a completely different method with canvas.php (Resizing script)

Answer (score 0):

For your first error you're passing **$newimage** to **imagecreatefromjpeg()**.  During this process **$newimage** does not have a value that **imagecreatefromjpeg()** can understand. So basically if **$newimage** is a file or directory, it's not valid so your problem is the value assigned to **$newimage**.(Make sure "../uploads/avatars/1380641918-4496.jpg" is valid) Not sure what to tell you on the second warning. Good Luck.